# LibGDX: Google Play Game Service (Dec 2016) - Cannot call Games class

Tags: android, libgdx, google-play-services

I'm trying to include Google Play Game Services in my Android game and I tried adding [BaseGameUtils](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Google-Play-Game-Services-in-LibGDX) library. But it is not really working.

I can call the `GameHelper` class from `AndroidLauncher` but not the `Games` class for getting leaderboards.

I also have this warning in my console: **(which does not interfere with the actual problem - see the answer)**

```
project ':android': Unable to resolve additional project configuration.
Details: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: Could not find property 'main' on SourceSet container.
```

Can somebody give any insight to this problem?

This is my android gradle: http://pastebin.com/ya85gGs4

And this my BaseGameUtils gradle: http://pastebin.com/0iyz2j12

Also the root gradle: http://pastebin.com/in2MmYMM

When I check Project Structure -> Problems, I have these messages:

[image: Project Structure]

**EDIT:** I have tried changing android support library, appcompat and google play services to different versions including the latest ones but this error keeps pissing me off.

---

**PS:** Please feel free to edit the title. I put the date because I wanted to imply that this is a recent issue.

Comment: Anybody has some suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spent the last 2 weeks trying to find a solution to this and it turns out I was using a 32-bit version of IntelliJ. All I had to do was to use the 64-bit program which is available in the same directory. <del>But I don't know how this solved the problem.</del> It's possibly because of the JRE used by the 32bit IDE. The 64bit IDE uses the java we installed while the 32bit one uses the java that's shipped with IDEA [as mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33010846/3058454).

I got the solution from another entirely different error debugging. They should have provided me with a better warning/error message. I stumbled [on this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35536013/3058454) while I was changing the JDK version in Maven settings of IntelliJ.

**EDIT:** I may have to mention that even now, the warning

```
project ':android': Unable to resolve additional project configuration.
Details: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: Could not find property 'main' on SourceSet container.
```

is still present. It is indeed caused by the inclusion of `BaseGameUtils` library but it does not interrupt getting the necessary library files.

---

### tl;dr

Use `idea64.exe` in `C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2016.3.2\bin` instead of `idea.exe`